# Flask logins without persistence

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

My company has a Flask application that uses flask-login to handle user logins/logouts and sessions. We use the @login_required decorator to protect views. Our clients log via persistent users stored in a database. However, we want employees of our company to be able to log in to our clients' sites without popping up in their users lists. We verify our own authenticity by CAS login at our own CAS server and checking that the username belongs to our company.

We want the employees to simply be able to login without needing to be persisted in the database but flask-login requires a persisted user model.

Sorry for the troublesome use of words here, but I hope this is understadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every authorization system should check user in some storage by some field and in usual cases return `exist` or `has permisions`.

So with `flask-login` you can implement it with next: `user_loader`/`header_loader`/`request_loader` and `UserMixin` with `user_id`.

Every request with `login_required` call `*_loader` to get `UserMixin`. So it can look like next:

```
@login_manager.request_loader
def loader(request):
    identifier = get_identifier_from_request(request)
    exist = check_on_cas_server(identifier)
    if not exist:
        return None
    user = UserMixin()
    user.id = get_specified_or_random_id(identifier, exist)
    return user
```

Details you can found with https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.